# Im trying to build an Installer for some packages that my programm needs. I also want to have a Status bar which shows the current progress

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing, subprocess

```
import tkinter as tk
import multiprocessing
from tkinter import messagebox

def installPackages_1(self):
    self.t = ""
    label = tk.Label(fenster, text="Checking for packages...").place(x=60, y=100)
    pb = ttk.Progressbar(fenster, orient='horizontal', mode='determinate', length=280)
    pb.place(x=180, y=100)
    fenster.update()
    packages = ["pandas", "openpyxl", "odfpy"]
    for i in packages:
        t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.installPackages_2(i))
        t1.start()
        pb['value'] += 100 / 3
        fenster.update()
    label1 = tk.Label(fenster, text="Done").place(x=30, y=100, width=450, height=25)
    fenster.update()
    m_text = "\nStatus:\n%s" % (self.t)
    tk.messagebox.showinfo(message=m_text, title="Installation")

def installPackages_2(self,package):
    s = ""
    s = str(subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', package]))[2:12]
    if s == "Collecting":
        self.t += "Package '%s' installed\n" % (package)
    else:
        self.t += "[OK]: Paket '%s' found\n" % (package)
```

When i convert my python programm into an .exe the tkinter window open up multiple times, I think this is caused because th subprocess interrupts the process of the tkinterr window. I tried to implement some kind of multiprocessing but it didnt change anything.I convert through auto-py-to-exe.

Answer (score 0):

Pyinstaller already bundles the libraries with your executable, you don't need to check for them.

checking for libraries and installing them is completely unnecessary (and isn't as simple as you expect), don't call either functions inside your executable and your app will work just fine, as you don't need to call them anyway.

needless to say checking for their existence this way will fail and will cause a lot of undesirable behavior, as the application is no longer running as a python executable on a script but as an embedded interpreter, in other words `sys.executable` no longer points to `python.exe`.

also the correct way to check that a certain library exists is to use, [importlib.util.find_spec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec), which should correctly work for frozen applications, but again, you don't need it for you executable because pyinstaller already packages all dependencies.

Comment: In python the standard way of specifying dependencies is to list them in a file called `requirements.txt`https://learnpython.com/blog/python-requirements-file your tooling should support this, hopefully